# What are the possible reasons behind "log4j: Error Could not find value for key log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER"

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j, tomcat7, pom.xml

I am wondering why I have this error when deploying my web application.

```
log4j: Error Could not find value for key log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER
```

Here is my `log4j.properties` file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=application.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, SQL_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

Do I have to do some configuration in the server side? I am running my application on a Tomcat 7 server. I added this dependency to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Others who were in the same situation as mine where the log4j.properties looks perfectly fine, please look out for other version of log4j.properties lurking somewhere on the classpath. I had a different file (probably for testing) with wrong settings and it was the culprit. Took some time to realize that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define `log.appender.SQL_APPENDER`, since you assign it in the line

```
 log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, SQL_APPENDER
```

You are defining appender `R` but no `SQL_APPENDER`

Comment: Thank you SJuan, I am actually not familiar at all with web applications, can you please explain to me how to define an SQL_APPENDER?

Comment: It is not a webapp issue but a log4j config issue. The easiest way would be copying the definition of `log.appender.R` to `log.appender.SQL_APPENDER` (change the `FILE` to a different destination)

Comment: @SJuan76 - I am having a similar issue. I did not get any answers so far. Can you please help me at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281667/error-cannot-log-with-log4j

Answer (score 1):

As SJuan mentioned you need to define

> log.appender.SQL_APPENDER

and that is done something like this :

> log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

and might as well add these while you are at it...

> log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER.File=c:/EC_sql.log
>   log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=1000KB 
>   log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=62 
>   log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
>   log4j.appender.SQL_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p [%t]
>   (%F:%L) - %m%n

Hope this helps someone!